# Удаление последнего введенного символа

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как реализовать удаление последнего введенного символа в textarea при событии keyup?

Comment: любой введенный символ должен удаляться?

Comment: @Ruslan_K да, любой

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$('#idOfTA').keyup(
  function(){
    var inputString = $('#idOfTA').val();
    var shortenedString = inputString.substr(0,(inputString.length -1));
    $('#idOfTA').val(shortenedString);
  });

$('#idOfTA2').keyup(
  function(){
    var max = 5;
    var len = this.value.length;
    //alert(len);
    if(len > max) {
      var inputString = $('#idOfTA2').val();
      var shortenedString = inputString.substr(0,(inputString.length -1));
      $('#idOfTA2').val(shortenedString);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post">
  <label for="idOfTA">Текст:</label>
  <textarea id="idOfTA" ></textarea> <br/>
  <label for="idOfTA2">Текст(не более 5ти символов):</label>
  <textarea id="idOfTA2" ></textarea>
</form>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, что то я сглупил)